# Java - take first letter of word and replace with first letter of another word

Tags: java, string, replace

I need to create a program that displays two words that a user has inputted then I need to display the first and last letter and the number of characters of those two words.

That part is fine. But next I need to switch the first letter of the first word with the first letter of the second word. And then the last letter of the first word with the last letter of the second word. And the same with the second word.

Then I need to do the same with the second word.

I used the code below but it replaces ALL the characters in the first word (that are the same character) with the character from the second word.

Please help. I've been trying to do this for hours!!! And I am very new to this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);

    String word_one;
    String word_two;
    System.out.print("Enter 2 words on one line separated by at least one space"
        + " (no white space allowed IN each word): ");
    word_one = user_input.next( );
    word_two = user_input.nextLine( );

    System.out.println("\nFirst word you entered is <"
        + word_one
        + "> which is "
        + word_one.length() 
        + " characters long.\nIt starts with the character '"
        + word_one.charAt(word_one.length() - word_one.length())
        + "' and ends with the character'"
        + word_one.charAt(word_one.length() - 1)
        + "'");

    System.out.println("\nSecond word you entered is <"
        + (word_two.replace(" ", ""))
        + "> which is "
        + (word_two.replace(" ", "")).length()
        + " characters long. \nIt starts with the character '"
        + word_two.charAt(word_two.length() - word_two.length() + 1)
        + "' and ends with the character'"
        + word_two.charAt(word_two.length() - 1) + "'");

    user_input.close();

    System.out.println("\nNew words: "
        + word_one.replace(
                word_one.charAt(word_one.length() - word_one.length()), 
                word_two.charAt(word_two.length() - word_two.length() + 1))
            .replace(
                word_one.charAt(word_one.length() - 1),
                word_two.charAt(word_two.length() - 1))
        + word_two.replace(
                word_two.charAt(word_two.length() - word_two.length() + 1),
                word_one.charAt(word_one.length() - word_one.length()))
            .replace(
                word_two.charAt(word_two.length() - 1),
                word_one.charAt(word_one.length() - 1)));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[`replace(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence)) replaces all the occurences of given substring with another substring. What you're looking for is [`replaceFirst(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceFirst(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) for replacement of first letter,  but replacing last one won't be so easy. In this case, I'd go with usage of [`substring(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int)) and manual concatenation.

Alternatively, you can use [`replaceAll(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) that works with [regular expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum) and use beginning/end of line/input constructs (`^$\A\Z`).

Comment: `StringBuilder` has a `reverse()` method which might prove useful.

Comment: char[] r = word_one.toCharArray(); you can convert your string into Character Array. Just get the first character from word_second and append into main string hope it will help you

Answer (score 0):

This is much easier if you work with char arrays rather than Strings. Then you can just point to the first (wordOne[0]) and last (wordOne[wordOne.length]) elements.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {


    public static void main(String[] args)

    {
        final Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter 2 words on one line separated by at least one space (no white space allowed IN"
                + " each word): ");

        final char[] wordOne = nextInput(userInput);
        final char[] wordTwo = nextInput(userInput);

        System.out.println("\nFirst word you entered is <" + stringOf(wordOne) + "> which is " + wordOne.length
                + " characters long.\nIt starts with the character '" + wordOne[(wordOne.length - wordOne.length)] + "' "
                + "and ends with the character'" + wordOne[wordOne.length - 1] + "'");

        System.out.println("\nSecond word you entered is <" + stringOf(wordTwo) + "> which is " + wordTwo.length + " characters long. \nIt starts with the character '" + wordTwo[0] +
                "' and ends with the character'" + wordTwo[wordTwo.length - 1] + "'");

        userInput.close();

        char[] newWordOne = wordOne.clone();
        newWordOne[0] = wordTwo[0];
        newWordOne[wordOne.length - 1] = wordTwo[wordTwo.length - 1];

        char[] newWordTwo = wordTwo.clone();
        newWordTwo[0] = wordOne[0];
        newWordTwo[wordTwo.length - 1] = wordOne[wordOne.length - 1];

        System.out.println("\nNew words: " + stringOf(newWordOne) + " " + stringOf(newWordTwo));
    }

    private static String stringOf(final char[] word) {
        return new String(word);
    }

    private static char[] nextInput(final Scanner scanner) {
        return scanner.next().trim().toCharArray();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the advice! But as it turns out all I need to do was use substrings and then concatenate them with the first and last letters of the words that I needed. Also, I needed to replace all the spaces " " with "" because it kept switching out letters and spaces and I did not want it to count the spaces.

Hope this helps others!